# Function pointer declaration misreads argument type

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have problems using a struct as an argument in the declaration of a function pointer (`MyFunction`) below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Record {
    int x, y;
};

// MyFunction returns a changed version of Record
typedef Record (*MyFunction)(const &Record, int);

// Increment record by change
Record add(const Record &rec, int change) {
    return Record{rec.x + change, rec.y + change};
}

// Apply a change to Record by function f
Record apply(MyFunction f, const Record &rec, int change) {
    return f(rec, change);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Record 
      myRec = {3,5},
      result = apply(add, myRec, 10); // compilation error here
    std::cout << result.x << " " << result.y << std::endl;
}
```

gcc (6.4.2) gives a compilation error in line 25 (marked above):
`invalid conversion from 'Record (*)(const Record&, int)' to 'MyFunction' {aka 'Record (*)(const int&, int)'}`

What? How come the declaration of `MyFunction` has turned the `const Record&` type into `const int&`?

Comment: Is this the **first** error message? GCC tends to recover from unknown types by replacing them with `int`s (just to print more error messages before stopping).

Comment: I get errors on this line `typedef Record (*MyFunction)(const &Record, int);`  please post the first error message(s).  See https://godbolt.org/z/7xYTeGons

Comment: Replacing unknown types with ints? Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to define a reference argument named Record without a type. It should be spelled like this if you meant a *reference to* `Record`:

```
typedef Record (*MyFunction)(const Record&, int);
```

Or rather:

```
using MyFunction = Record (*)(const Record&, int);
```

Comment: Dang! A simple typo. Thanks for the correction.